# I want to have one div centered inside another with another div centered below that.

Tags: html, css, positioning

Here is my CSS and html:

```css
.container {
 background-image: url('./images/bg.jpg');
 height: 500px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}

.logo {
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 960px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 top: 200px;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li {
 display: inline;
}

.nav {
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 padding-right: 35px;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="logo">
  <h1>My Page</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

I don't think they way I've positioned the `<div class="logo"></div>` is probably correct but I'm not sure how to centre content within a div and any solution I find seems to affect the positioning of `<div class="nav"></div>`.

So this question is two-fold - how can I position `<div class="logo"></div>` centrally within `<div class="container"></div>` and then how can I place `<div class="nav"></div>` below `<div class="logo"></div>`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: with the nav menu below the header if possible and also both centered vertically in the first div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to do that.
https://jsfiddle.net/bjdvz1km/

```css
.container {
 background-image: url('./images/bg.jpg');
 height: 500px;
 width: 960px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
}

.logo {
 margin: auto;
 width: 960px;
 height: 100px;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li {
 display: inline;
}

.nav {
 margin: auto;
 padding-right: 35px;
 clear: both;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>My Page</h1>
  </div>
  
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you want to relatively position both divs, an easy way to center a relatively positioned item inside its parent container is using left: 50%, transform: translateX(-50%).

```css
.container {
 background-image: url('./images/bg.jpg');
 height: 500px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: auto;
}

.logo {
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 width: 960px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li {
 display: inline;
}

.nav {
 margin: auto;
    position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 padding-right: 35px;
 clear: both;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="logo">
  <h1>My Page</h1>
 </div>
 
 <div class="nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    background-image: url('./images/bg.jpg');
    height: 500px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

.logo {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    dispaly: block;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}



<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <h1>My Page</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Is this what you want?